# Are mini display ports to VGA reversible?

Tags: vga, mini-displayport

So I need an adapter for a Mini Display port monitor to go to a VGA laptop. Every adapter I see says it's for the opposite. Are mini DP to VGA cables reversible?

Answer (score 0):

You might be reading them the wrong way around. The image signal goes from the computer to the monitor. It is common to write that in this format, thus you are looking for VGA/[DB5HD](https://superuser.com/questions/541202/what-exactly-is-vga-and-what-is-the-difference-between-it-and-a-video-card/541211#541211) to DP.

VGA is an ancient **analog** signal.
Display port uses **digital** signal.

Thus you will need a device which can read one form, and output the other form. This is not symmetrical and you can only use such a device in a single direction.

On other words: No, you can not turn the 'cable' around an expect it to work because it is not just a cable.